# I get an error cannot implicity convert type int? to int. An expicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Tags: c#

I am new to this but this comes from a form where a user picks how many numbers they want generated then they input their starting number range, from there the code should get the check digit from the number and then create the other numbers in similar fashion

```
     private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
          {
            using (StreamWriter objWriter = new StreamWriter("C:\\temp\\Test.txt"))
            {
             int numpins = int.Parse(textBox1.Text); //creates a number counter for input
             string basepin = textBox2.Text; //user is going to input how many numbers to create
             int pinlength = basepin.Length;
             string formatspecifier = "{0:d" + pinlength.ToString() + "}";
             long pinnumber = long.Parse(basepin);

             for (int d = 0; d < numpins; d++)
                {
                GetCheckDigit(dig);//Calling the function here
                basepin = string.Format(formatspecifier, pinnumber);
                objWriter.WriteLine(basepin);
                pinnumber++;
                }

                objWriter.Close();
                }

              }
```

Here is the function

```
  private static string GetCheckDigit(string dig)
       {
        var sum = 0;
        var result = true;
        var digits = dig?.ToCharArray();
        for (int? i = digits?.Length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
            {
             var num = digits[i]- 48; //the error is here (digits[i])
                if (result)
                {
                    num *= 2;
                    if (num > 9)
                        num -= 9;
                }
                sum += num;
                result = !result;
            }
            if ((sum % 10) == 0)
            {
                return "0";
            }
            return (10 - (sum % 10)).ToString();

        }
```

Comment: Use the `Value` property of the nullable type

Comment: Well the error is clear, a `int?` is not an `int` - though honestly the loop is already a strange start, you don't have any "backup plan" in case `digits` is `null`

Comment: basically: `int?` can be `null`, `int` *cannot* make your i a regular int, and use a null check for `dig` before even splicing it into an array.

Comment: Thanks removing all the "?" took away those errors but now I have a new error.             var digits = dig.ToCharArray();  Object reference not set to an instance of an object dig was null.  I have not checked to see if dig was null yet.

Comment: Where is `dig` defined? I don't see it in your code. Did you mean to pass `d` in instead?

Comment: at the very top it is "public string dig = default;"

Comment: Not sure how this works but I have done what you guys suggest and all errors are gone but only one problem,  The Getcheckdigit(dig) function is not getting passed at all now.  It totally skips it and continues to run my code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get rid of all the `.?` operators and just check if `dig` is null at the start of the method.

Comment: thank you that helped but have a new error with var digits = dig.ToCharArray(); Object reference not set to an instance of an object. dig was null.  so I guess this is where the check for dig is null comes in at

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `int?` is actually a different type than `int`. `int?` is actually an alias for `Nullable<Int32>` whereas `int` is an alias for `Int32`. The difference is that `int?` is a reference type that might be `null` but `int` is a value type that cannot be `null`.

If there's an actual possibility that `i` will be `null`, you should explicitly check for that and then use `i.Value`.

Also, is it actually possible that `dig` is `null`? Is this a valid input? If it *is* possible, you might want to consider checking it in the beginning of the method and handling it accordingly.

Comment: Thank you, I am in the process of checking to see if dig is null after getting an error with var digits = dig.ToCharArray(); Object reference not set to an instance of an object. dig was null

Comment: No it would not be a valid input so I am guessing i need to check to see if dig is null then do something else do something